# linked server Error

Tags: sql-server-2005

following error occur when i try to insert record from SQL server 2000 to SQL server 2005, while select query is running fine

OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "insight_db" returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "insight_db" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 10053, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
TCP Provider: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Comment: Usually this means bad router or switch, failing netowrk card or cable, broken firewall - anything related to network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If the insertion is convoluted can you do it with a stored procedure? Minimise the size of the chunk of info passing between DBs. Then check the network traffic: is the link being overwhelmed with competing "stuff" ?